# Как запросить у компилятора какой стандарт используется по умолчанию?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, linux-mint, clang

Хочу узнать какой стандарт используют компиляторы `clang` и `gcc` для компиляции по умолчанию.

Comment: Какой именно версии? :) Вопрос некорректен...

Comment: В чем именно он не корректен? У меня есть две линуксовые системы какой-то дам давности и мне нужно выяснить какой стандарт использует gcc для компиляции по умолчанию - что сдесь не корректно?

Comment: Потому что вы не говорите, какой именно давности. Вы понимаете, что одно дело что-то типа gcc 1.2, и совсем другое - gcc 7.8? Блин, кажется, дошло, что вы хотите - как **запросить у компилятора** используемую им версию стандарта, а не просто узнать, "какой стандарт использует по умолчанию обобщенный компилятор gcc". Если это так - сформулируйте свой вопрос более точно, не ленитесь...

Comment: ок, исправил - надеюсь так понятней)

Comment: Не особо, давность так и не указали

Comment: Мне списком вывести или как? Я не спрашиваю: какой стандарт у такого-то компилятора, я спрашиваю: как это узнать/запросить.

Comment: А, нуок, только вот заголовок и текст вопроса немного расходятся)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null` заставит компилятор выдать на стандартный выход все макро, предопределенные компилятором. Оттуда можно уже выдернуть `__STDC__` и `__STDC_VERSION__`. `__STDC_VERSION__` и будет описывать версию стандарта.

Надо также иметь в виду, что в C89/90 макроса `__STDC_VERSION__` не было.

Comment: не отличает gnu* и iso* версии, для плюсов тоже не сработает...

Comment: @Fat-Zer: Если я не ошибаюсь, gnu версии являются conforming implementations, т.е. содержат лишь *расширения* стандарта, но не нарушения стандарта. Т.е. в отличении gnu версий задачи не стояло. Во вторых, никакие "плюсы" к данному вопросу отношения не имеют.

Comment: ага, не работает для плюсов

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch: При чем здесь "плюсы" в вопросе по С? Откуда вдруг взялись "плюсы"?

Comment: я просто подтвердил что да - для плюсов не работает - и все.

Comment: И для Фортрана не работает тоже. А С++ компилятор определит макро `__cplusplus`, которое будет видно точно таким же образом.

Comment: @AnT, я удивлён, что не нахожу какого-либо способа (окромя препроцессирования/сборки относительно сложных примеров) запросить стандарт по умолчанию у компилятора в общем случае (про __cplusplus, честно сказать, забыл). Понятно, что практической ценности в этом особо нет, но всё же как-то странно.

Comment: @Fat-Zer: По-видимому у нас несколько разное понимание "стандарта" в данном контексте. Вышеприведенный способ полностью закрывает вопрос. Не вижу необходимости в "сложных примерах".

Comment: @AnT, да, пожалуй... я понимаю вопрос скорее так, что результат запроса должен выходить взаимооднозначным с аргументом `-std` с точностью до синонимов, что для си, что для плюсов. Повторюсь, что рассматриваю это чисто как некий «интересный факт» без особой практической пользы.

Comment: Согласен с FAT-ZER - тоже думал что так должно быть